# Sudden complaint that Windows is not genuine - some questions

Tags: windows-server-2008

I used to use VMWare Workstation and made several VMs with Win Server 2008, which worked fine. My first tasks were to setup RDP, updates, and activate the OS.

I deleted Workstation and thus did not have my VMs available to use for about 2 months. Now I have VMWare Server 2.0.2 as I this is free and I am going to get Hyper-V on a host Win Server in about March, but when I have accessed one of my VMs (haven't tried the others yet), it complains that the copy of Windows is not genuine.

I now have a black screen but can access all my apps on the VM. Will the OS eventually shut me out from accessing it?

I got my key from the Action Pack but the standard R2 key has been taken down and replaced with the Enteprise R2 key. I have Enterprise R2 but apparently the autorun is corrupt!

Thanks

Comment: Is the question about the OS shutting you out the only part of this you want an answer for, or is there another question implied here?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like Magical Jelly Bean Key Finder (http://www.magicaljellybean.com/) to confirm what license key is registered by your system.

If you installed and used a license key which is now invalid, Microsoft does provide license key update utilities. I have used the utility for Windows XP.